# perl: что это за структура данных и как с ней работать?

Tags: массивы, perl

```
my $poly  = [ [0,0], [0,2], [2,2], [2,0] ];
```

это что то типа ссылки на анонимный массив массивов?

мне нужно добавить не четыре подмассива из двух элементов, а, например, 1000, как это можно сделать? я бы сгенерировал через eval строку. но это как то извращенно. может както можно по другому? И как распечатать такого типа массив?

спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

```
my $poly  = [ [0,0], [0,2], [2,2], [2,0] ];  # ссылка на пустой массив $poly =[];

# Можно так, если массив можно собрать тут же:
push @{$poly}, [3,0];

# Или так, если массив где то еще:
my @arr=(3,0);
push @{$poly}, \@arr;

# Или так
$poly->[4]=[3,0];

# Ну и скажем обращение к элементу вложенного массива
print $poly->[1]->[1];  # 2
```

Не знаю в каком виде вы бы хотели его напечатать, вот так его можно обходить, углубляясь в структуру:

```
for( @{$poly} ) {
  for( @{$_} ) {
    print;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 4):

Обычный массив создаётся в скобках (1,2,3), а это ссылка на массив [1,2,3]. Получается в вашем случае имеем ссылку на массив из ссылок на массивы [[1,2],[3,4]], такое в перле используется тоже часто. Вывести можно его с помощью Data::Dumper (который может кстати вывести произвольную по вложенности сложную структуру), также можно вручную. Добавлять элемент как и в обычный массив `push @$poly, [1,2]`, но при этом нужно разыменовывать ссылку (дополнительный @ в начале), либо можно разыменовывать через стрелку `$poly->[0]` (где 0 это индекс). Вот код ([запустить онлайн](http://tpcg.io/pgGC8W)):

```
use Data::Dumper;

# Создаём массив вручную
my $poly  = [ [0,0], [0,2], [2,2], [2,0] ];
# Выводим через Dumper
print Dumper($poly);

# Заполняем массив в цикле
$poly = [];
for $i (0..9) {
    push @$poly, [$i, $i + 1];
}
# Выводим через Dumper
print Dumper($poly);

# Выводим массив вручную
for $i (0..scalar(@$poly) - 1) {
    print "[", $poly->[$i]->[0], ",", $poly->[$i]->[1], "] ";
}
print "\n";

# Также можно вывести весь массив таким навороченным синтаксисом
print "[" . join(", ", map { "[" . join(", ", @$_) . "]" } @$poly) . "]\n";
```

Comment: Громадное спасибо!